# Facebook webhook not triggered for feed updates

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I subscribed my app to the feed event. I can check the subscribtion using

```
GET /{{app_id}}/subscriptions?access_token={{app_access_token}}
```

which returns

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "object": "page",
            "callback_url": "https://f0e769f1.ngrok.io/api/facebook/webhook",
            "active": true,
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "messages",
                    "version": "v3.0"
                },
                {
                    "name": "feed",
                    "version": "v3.0"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I check that my test page is subscribed with

```
GET /{{test_page_id}}/subscribed_apps?access_token={{test_page_access_token}}
```

and it returns:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "link": "https://localhost:3000/",
            "name": "xxxxxxx",
            "id": "xxxxxxxx"
        }
    ]
}
```

`
However, I don't receive any updates on my callback url when a subscribed page changes. I tried

- Creating a new post
- Commenting on an existing post
- Liking a post
  The messages event works fine. My app is still in development.

Comment: Anybody care to comment why this questions has been downvoted?

Comment: I also have same problem with my facebook app that is under development... Have you got any solution till now?

Comment: Unfortunately I have not. I submitted by app for review and are planing to test it again when the app is in production.

Comment: @FrederikClaus did you solve this problem?